# explode() doesn't work on get_the_author_meta('description');

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, explode

I am using the `get_the_author_meta('description')` function to get the author description in WordPress with this code:

```
$author_desc = get_the_author_meta('description');
$author_data = explode('>', $author_desc);
var_dump($author_data);
```

With the description being: `E-commerce consultant>man>het e-commerce`. I want the explode function to create 3 array items, splitting the string by '>'.

But the result is this:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'E-commerce consultant&gt;man&gt;het e-commerce' (length=46)
```

It seems that it DOES put the string in an array, but creates only one row...

Comment: Maybe use str_replace to replace the > with another set of characters, such as <br /> and then explode by <br />.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `>` char there is entity `&gt;`. Sou you can explode by this entity string:

```
$author_desc = get_the_author_meta('description');
$author_data = explode('&gt;', $author_desc); // explode by &gt; instead of >
var_dump($author_data);
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/549765)**

Comment: Not *maybe*, that surely is the case :)